Pilot in jail tries to avenge son's death
I was child when I saw this movie, possibly in 1985-1995. I don't know it's name  or the actors, but I know the story, I will explain it and it will be great if you realize and just give me the name, I want to watch it again badly!
This is the story I remember: the main character is a pilot and his wife is a photographer, they had a little boy (5 years old), something happens and he went to jail, bad people attack his family and his wife survives but not their son.
The thing that makes it different from other movies is that one night he escaped from the jail and no one understands how, killed some people and returned before morning.
The head of the bad people was a man which used drugs and was in the same jail. His men came and freed him. In the beginning of the movie he has a luxury red car which is destroyed.
And from one scene in the jail, one of the prisoners counting 98,99... when another prisoner was doing push-ups and suddenly the head of bad men put his leg on his back. I can say it was English, I guess the movie was American.

The Escapist with Jonny Lee Miller is about a pilot who goes to prison (and escapes several times) to find the guy who attacked his family. But his wife died in the attack (and I don't think there's a son).

no this is not,it is for 2002,I am 24 now,when I saw this movie I was 5 or 6,I remember it was on VHS!

OK, thanks. Edited the question. Can you explain the sentence "counting 98,99... when other prisoner was pushing up", though? Do you mean he was doing push-ups?

yes and it seemed that he was making a new records!I remember the rest ...he was doing push ups and he reached to 98,99 suddenly the head of bad men put his leg on his back,he tolerated for seconds but not successful to go on!

Could this be Law Abiding Citizen?


A frustrated man decides to take justice into his own hands after a
  plea bargain sets one of his family's killers free. He targets not
  only the killer but also the district attorney and others involved in
  the deal.

He is incarcerated for the whole movie, and the investigating officers are trying to figure out who he has working for him on the outside.
It turns out he is sneaking out of prison to enact vengeance directly...

no this is not,I have seen this.the movie I mentioned was older,maybe between 1985 - 1995!I guess.
